# Modifying Values in a For Each Loop - Any Way?

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I know this goes against the .NET rules, but sometimes I need it. For example, I need to run through a `Dictionary<string, bool>`. This dictionary stores my variables in a parsed logic equation. I want to output a truth table, so I need to iterate through and set elements.

One thing I've tried is

```
        foreach (var x in Variables.Keys)
        {
            bool on = ((in) & (j << in)) > 0;
            Variables[x] = on;
            builder.Append(on == true ? '1' : '0').Append('\t');
            j++;
        }
```

I just get a `InvalidOperationException`: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. I converted the dictionary to an array and tried to modify it that way, but `KeyValuePair.Value` is *readonly*, so it won't work.

Comment: ^ should actually be an answer imho.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a copy of the key collection:

```
foreach (var x in Variables.Keys.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot edit `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in loop.

Try this:

```
var resultVariables = new Dictionary<string, bool>(Variables.Count);

foreach (var x in Variables.Keys)
{
     bool on = ((in) & (j << in)) > 0;
     resultVariables[x] = on;
     builder.Append(on == true ? '1' : '0').Append('\t');
     j++;
}

Variables = resultVariables;
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a copy of the collection first, then I'd iterate over the copy allowing me to mess with the original as required.